# Kaggle notebook not showing in my work tab of the competition

Tags: kaggle, gemma

I have submitted [my kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/abzshaikh/explain-kaggle-solutions-using-rag-and-vector-db) note but it doesn't show in the my work tab of the [competition](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/data-assistants-with-gemma/code). Tried reaching people on kaggle had no luck. How should I associate the notebook with competition?

I added the competition through 'add input' button on the user interface, it is still not showing.